# Does pytest use the dependency chain to determine when a fixture yields?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have three test modules: `testmodule_one`, `testmodule_two`, and `testmodule_three`.

`testmodule_two` and `testmodule_three` depend on `testmodule_one`.

I have a global fixture defined in `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def integration_test_cleanup():
    yield
    # Do my tear down routines
```

I was hoping to centralize all my tear down routines in this one fixture.

But what happens if `testmodule_one`, `testmodule_two`, and `testmodule_three` all use `integration_test_cleanup` that has a module scope?

Will pytest see that `testmodule_two` and `testmodule_three` depend on `testmodule_one` and not yield until they are finished? Or will it yield immediately after `testmodule_one` finishes?

I ask because I'm wondering if I could avoid breaking out integration_test_cleanup into pieces that are scoped at the session and module level.

Does pytest follow the dependency chain and use it to determine when to yield?

Comment: I believe after `testmodule_one` finishes the teardown will be called. I'm curious how (or what makes) your modules depend on eachother?